# Light switch with 3 SPDT switches?

Tags: switches, circuit-design, spdt

In the below circuit, I have two switches that can turn the light on or off from those two locations. Any 'switch' will turn the lights into the opposite position:

[image]

[image]

How could a circuit be made to control light from 3 or 4 locations instead of just two?

Comment: [Multi-way switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_switching)

Comment: Use a cross switch in the middle.

Comment: @EugeneSh. see updated screenshot please.

Comment: @TomKuschel this component? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossbar_switch. Would it be possible to show how this would look in an example?

Comment: @David542 no crossbar :-O I usually call it cross switch possibly a false friend from German language "Kreuzschalter". You made my day!

Comment: @TomKuschel It's probably the 4-way switch? Looks like an `X` on diagrams

Comment: A double-pole, double-throw (DPDT) "reversing" switch is used. Be sure it does not have a center-off position. Example: https://www.amazon.com/Leviton-COMMERCIAL-Toggle-Switch-5504-2I/dp/B00002N7IH/ref=sr_1_44

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use any number of DPDT switches in between : )

For example, with three switches like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8cWH4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

and four switches like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQuDW9.png)</sup>

And so forth and so forth! Here's an example for five switches:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKb7se.png)</sup>